# Android 8 forgets I have permission in my foreground service. BLE scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I start a service with `startService`( tried also `startForegroundService`) and move it immediately to foreground with the `startForeground()` and then in the service I create a thread where I start BLE scanning for 15 minutes after which I stop the BLE scanning and immediately after that I restart the BLE scanning for 15 minutes and so on.

Permission is requested and approved on the activity when I run the app. And then I lock the screen with the device button leaving the foreground service running and scanning BLE and reading data from the BLE devices.

This works without problems if I run it on Android 7. But when I am running it on Android 8 I get this:

```
03-23 17:58:26.887 18038-18055 W/Binder: Binder call
failed.

java.lang.SecurityException: Need ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to get scan results at 
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1942)
```

I have implemented `onBind()` method so that it throws exception if called. Could this be the reason? But why on the Android 8 `onBind()` would be called on service if not on Android 7? **Edit** changed `onBind()` to return null, no effect.

The minSdkVersion as well as targetSdkVersion are both 23.

**Edit** Does Android 8 require that a long running foreground service service checks and request for permissions every time e.g. when BLE scan is started eventhough the permissions were already checked and requested succesfully for in the activity when app was started? As far as I know permissions can not be requested in service, you need activity for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have this exception, because Location permission hasn't been granted on Android 8 device

Comment: That can't be the case as my activity request for this permission and the Ble scanning works even when I lock the screen. But after 15 minutea when the Ble scanning is stopped and restarted I get this.

If the app is runnimg on Foreground (screen not locked) ir runs Without problems. So it seems that the problem is somehow related to service being run for 15 minutes when screen is locked.

I tried to change the Ble scanning stop and restart every five minutes and it seems working at least for 10 minutes. Need to continue on Monday...